# Heading UITableView issue in ios8

Tags: objective-c, ipad, storyboard, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using splitviewcontroller into my app.depends on selection in master view.......deatil view will appear........we are having  multiple detail view.
 This my code to call the detail view

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    [self.navigationController setDelegate:self];

    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
    }

    if([[self.detailItem description] isEqualToString:@"Companies"])
    {
        listViewController_ = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ListStoryBoard"];
        [self addChildViewController:listViewController_];

        if (![[PSAWebServices sharedInstance] isPushInProcess])      {

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:listViewController_ animated:YES];
        }


    }

    else if ([[self.detailItem description] isEqualToString:@"Contacts"])
    {
        contactlistViewController_ = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contactListView"];
        [self addChildViewController:contactlistViewController_];

        if (![[PSAWebServices sharedInstance] isPushInProcess])
        {
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:contactlistViewController_ animated:YES];
        }
    }

    else if ([[self.detailItem description] isEqualToString:@"Projects"])
    {
        projectViewController_ = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"projectListView"];
        [self addChildViewController:projectViewController_];
        if (![[PSAWebServices sharedInstance] isPushInProcess])
        {
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:projectViewController_ animated:YES];
        }
    }
    else if ([[self.detailItem description] isEqualToString:@"Activities"])
    {
        activitiesViewController_ = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"activityListView"];
        [self addChildViewController:activitiesViewController_];
        if (![[PSAWebServices sharedInstance] isPushInProcess])
        {
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:activitiesViewController_ animated:YES];
        }
    }

    else if ([[self.detailItem description] isEqualToString:@"Calendar"])
    {
        calendarViewController_ = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CalendarStoryBoard"];
        //[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
        [self addChildViewController:calendarViewController_];
        //[self.view addSubview:self.calendarViewController.view];
        //[self.navigationController pushViewController:calendarViewController_ animated:YES];


        if (![[PSAWebServices sharedInstance] isPushInProcess])
        {

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:calendarViewController_ animated:YES];
        }

    }


}
```

here is problem which come only first time 
[image]
My question is I am  not able to set the frame of the detail view in ios8 with using the Auto layout and constraints
can u plz help me out this?
Thanks in advance

but i when rotated device it get fit correctly in screen 
where i am getting wrong

Comment: I have the UISearchbar and UItableview in Detailviewcontroller 
Uitable view and search bar is not get fit